# Mongo DB 4.0 Transactions With Mongoose & NodeJs, Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions, acid

I am developing an application where I am using MongoDB as database with Nodejs + Express in application layer, I have two collections, namely

1. users
2. transactions

Here i have to update wallet of thousands of users with some amount and if successful create a new document with related info for each transaction, This is My code :

```
 userModel.update({_id : ObjectId(userId)}, {$inc : {wallet : 500}}, function (err, creditInfo) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);                            
    }
    if(creditInfo.nModified > 0) {
        newTransModel = new transModel({
            usersId: ObjectId(userId),            
            amount: winAmt,         
            type: 'credit',           
        }); 
        newTransModel.save(function (err, doc) {
            if(err){
                Cb(err); 
            }
        });
    }                            
});
```

but this solution is not `atomic` there is always a possibility of user wallet updated with amount but related transaction not created in transactions collection resulting in financial loss.

I have heard that recently `MongoDB` has added `Transactions` support in its `4.0 version`, I have read the MongoDB docs but couldn't get it to successfully implement it **with mongoose in Node.js**, can anyone tell me how this above code be reimplemented using the latest `Transactions` feature of MongoDB which have these functions

```
Session.startTransaction()
Session.abortTransaction()
Session.commitTransaction()
```

MongoDB Docs : [Click Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> with mongoose in Node.js, can anyone tell me how this above code be reimplemented using the latest Transactions feature

To use [MongoDB multi-documents transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/) support in [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) you need version greater than v5.2. For example:

```
npm install mongoose@5.2
```

Mongoose transactional methods returns a promise rather than a session which would require to use `await`. See:

- [Transactions in Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html)
- [Blog: A Node.JS Perspective on MongoDB 4.0: Transactions](http://thecodebarbarian.com/a-node-js-perspective-on-mongodb-4-transactions.html)

For example, altering the example on the resource above and your example, you can try:

```
const User = mongoose.model('Users', new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: String, wallet: Number
}));
const Transaction = mongoose.model('Transactions', new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: ObjectId, amount: Number, type: String
}));

await updateWallet(userId, 500);

async function updateWallet(userId, amount) {
  const session = await User.startSession();
  session.startTransaction();
  try {
    const opts = { session };
    const A = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { _id: userId }, { $inc: { wallet: amount } }, opts);

    const B = await Transaction(
                    { usersId: userId, amount: amount, type: "credit" })
                    .save(opts);

    await session.commitTransaction();
    session.endSession();
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    // If an error occurred, abort the whole transaction and
    // undo any changes that might have happened
    await session.abortTransaction();
    session.endSession();
    throw error; 
  }
}
```

> is not atomic there is always a possibility of user wallet updated with amount but related transaction not created in transactions collection resulting in financial loss

You should also consider changing your MongoDB [data models](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/data-modeling-introduction/). Especially if the two collections are naturally linked. See also [Model data for Atomic Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/model-data-for-atomic-operations/) for more information.

An example model that you could try is [Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) model. Create a transaction entry first as an event, then recalculate the user's wallet balance using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

For example:

```
{tranId: 1001, fromUser:800, toUser:99, amount:300, time: Date(..)}
{tranId: 1002, fromUser:77, toUser:99, amount:100, time: Date(..)}
```

Then introduce a process to calculate the amount for each users per period as a cache depending on requirements (i.e. per 6 hours). You can display the current user's wallet balance by adding:

- The last cached amount for the user
- Any transactions for the user occur since the last cached amount. i.e. 0-6 hours ago.

Comment: there are two things about this
1) await updateWallet(userId, 500); <<< this gives an error saying await needs to be in a async function , top level await is not allowed

2) as i am doing this in loop async eachseries i.e updating many users wallet , i am getting writeconflit error of transactions & when i call next iteration, also using a finally block after try catch also doesn't work

Comment: This is an example, you'd have to adjust for your own use case. 1) Make sure you create an async function as shown above.  2) You can try performing [bulkWrite()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#bulkwrite_bulkWrite) within a transaction instead.

Comment: thanks for assistance, i already implemented this successfully, the second error was my coding mistake not an issue of the code.

Comment: just you edit your answer and edit this >> User.db.startSession(); to Mymodel.startSession() ........it says db is undefined, we can use any  mongoose model to start session its not scoped to that model once created.

Comment: Ah yes, I was trying to give emphasis that the session for for the database not on the collection, but made a mistake. Fixed now. thanks.

Comment: question: I don't see any use of .endSession(), could somebody care to explain whether we should need it or not?

Comment: @WanBachtiar how oo i add new: true as well as sessions in 3rd param?

Comment: @Yogesh ..... like in mysql even this works on a session which mongodb creates, eveithing is registered on a session and only written to db when you call committ, its a good practice to end the session when your work is done like we do end connection in mysql, its good for your server resources too & security.

Comment: Well, in that case, @WanBachtiar, it would a good idea to add a `finally` block to `endSession()`. It would a) save a code line b) would guarantee the execution.

Comment: @GauravKumar, that comment was supposed to go to Kannan T right ?

Comment: @Yogesh, that would be your choice on how to structure your code. The example above is to show how a transaction based on a session is started and committed/aborted.

Comment: @KannanT .....   i think you can just declare an object in their third parameter something like this { session : session , new : true }

Comment: @WanBachtiar ...yes it was for kannan T......mentioned you by mistake !!

Comment: MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object] 

I have got this error. What can I do for this

Comment: @WanBachtiar Can we handle concurrent error with transaction ? I mean if I update 2 times to 1 record so fast, and it's updated to the same __v of record so the concurrency updating is happen, if it's throw to catch, can I abort transaction or the concurrent error can happen even transaction is not committed ?

Comment: Would this still work properly if the two queries would be executed in parallel using await Promise.all?

Comment: Fantastic, thanks !

Comment: I have just one question, don't we have to start the session of Transaction model too?
As we have done for User model.