# Using transactions in mongoose throws an error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Taking cue from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51228059/mongo-db-4-0-transactions-with-mongoose-nodejs-express), I tried to implement MongoDB's new transactions feature using Mongoose 5.2.13. Here's my attempt:

```
addPost: async (parent, args) => {
  // Add new post to dbPosts
  const session = await dbPost.startSession();
  session.startTransaction();
  try {
    const opts = { session };
    const q1 = await dbPost({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      title: args.title,
      content: args.content,
      author: {
        id: args.author_id,
        first_name: args.author_first_name,
        last_name: args.author_last_name,
      }
    }).save(opts);
    const q2 = await dbUser.findOneAndUpdate(
      {_id: args.author_id},
      {$push: {posts:
        {
          id: 'a14def', // need access to the _id field from q1
          title: args.title,
          content: args.content,
        }
      }},
    opts);
    await session.commitTransaction();
    session.endSession();
  } catch(err) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    session.endSession();
    console.log('ERRORS:\n-----------\n' + err);
    console.log('\n------------\n\n');
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Running the above code, however, is returning the following error:

> BSON field 'insert.autocommit' is an unknown field.

What does it mean and what part of my code is causing it? Also, how do I access the *_id* generated by the first operation (`.save()` in this case) for use in the second operation (`.findOneAndUpdate()` in this case)? Currently, I am just hardwiring a dummy value there:

```
id: 'a14def'
```

Comment: Are you using a fresh MongoDB 4.0 installation or an updated one that used to be an older version?

Comment: I haven't installed Mongo locally. My collections are in a MongoDB Atlas account.

Comment: Are you sure it's running v4.0?

Comment: Also, do you have a replica set configured somehow? I am not using Atlas so this might be a given. But you need a replica set in order to run transactions: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#transactions

Comment: I do have replica sets with 3 nodes configured as a default Atlas feature. However, it seems my cluster is running version 3.6.7. And there isn't any way for me as the user to change that (the version option is disabled).

Comment: Well, that would explain the error. ;) Try this: https://resources.mongodb.com/mongodb-atlas-tutorial-kit/tutorial-upgrading-your-major-version-with-mongodb-atlas

Comment: Okay, turns out M0 users are only allowed 3.6.7 on Atlas, so that's a bummer. Thanks for pointing out the issue. So do you think that should be the only bottleneck here, I mean no code gremlins in the snippet I've posted?

Comment: Nothing that strikes me as a guaranteed fail but I'm not a mongoose pro.