# How to use mongoose transactions with updateMany?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the mongoose `updateMany()` method and I also want to keep it a part of transaction. The documentation shows the example of `save()` where I can do something like `Model.save({session: mySession})` but don't really know how to use it with for example `Model.updateMany()`

**UPDATE:**
For example I have two models called `SubDomain` and `Service` and they look like this respectively:

SUB-DOMAIN

```
{
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  url: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  services: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Service",
    },
  ],
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
}
```

SERVICE:

```
{
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: { type: Number },
  tags: { type: Array },
  packages: [
    {
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      description: { type: String, required: true },
      price: { type: Number, required: true },
    },
  ],
  map: { type: String },
  isHidden: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false,
  },
  sortingOrder: { type: Number },
  isForDomain: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
  isForSubDomain: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
  subDomains: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "SubDomain",
    },
  ],
}
```

Now the main field here is the `services` field in `SubDomain` and `subDomains` field in `Service`.

The complicated part:
Whenever the user wants to create new `service`, I want to `$push` that `service`'s `_id` into the array of `services` of all the `subDomains` inside that new `service`

And for that, I am using the `updateMany()` like this:

```
 const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
  sess.startTransaction();

const newService = new Service({
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  subDomains: req.body.subDomains
  ...foo
})

await SubDomain.updateMany(
        { _id: { $in: req.body.subDomains } },
        { $push: { services: newService._id } }
      );
```

The problem starts here, of course I can do:

```
newService.save({session: sess})
```

but how do I keep my `SubDomain`'s `updateMany` in the same `transaction` (i.e `sess`)

*I know my example is difficult to wrap your head around but I have tried to pick a simplest example rather than copying the exact same code which would have been a lot more difficult*

Comment: here is the example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992810/update-many-in-mongoose

Comment: Here is an example of Mongoose transactions on an update operation: [Mongo DB 4.0 Transactions With Mongoose & NodeJs, Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51228059/mongo-db-4-0-transactions-with-mongoose-nodejs-express)

Comment: Actually, I guess the reference posted by @prasad_ will solve my issue, do I need to do something like: `SubDomain.updateMany(
        foo,
        bar,
        { session: sess }
      );
    }`